# Find the Mobius Transformation for the following conditions.

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

**Answer the following**

(a) Find the Mobius Transformation that maps the line $Im z=1$ to the line $Rez=2$

(b) Find the Mobius Transformation that maps the line $Im z=1$ to the line $Rez=2,$ while mapping the point $i$ to the pount $2+10i$

(c) Find the Mobius Transformation that maps the circle $|z-1|=2$ to the circle $|z-3i|=4$

(d) Find the Mobius Transformation that maps the circle $|z-1|=2$ to the circle $|z-3i|=4,$ while mapping the point 3 to the point $-i.$

**My attempt**
(a) I am able to transform the line $Im z=1$ to the line $Rez=2$ by rotation of $\pi/2$ translation of 2 unit along real axis. Similarly I could informally give the solution. How do I solve the problem formally?
I could find the blinear transformation, if $z_1 \to w_1$, $z_2 \to w_2$ and $z_3 \to w_3$. using cross ratio. Can I use crossratio method here?

Comment: You rotate by $\frac{\pi}{2}$. That's $z\mapsto \mathrm iz$. Then you translate by $2$ to the right. That's $z\mapsto z+2$. Now just compose the two maps to get $z\mapsto \mathrm iz+2$.

Comment: Technical point: in many of these parts, there are infinitely many possible solutions, so the question should be asking for "a" transformation, not "the" transformation.